# Подсчет количества значений в столбце

Tags: excel, vba

Нужно подсчитать количество значений в столбцах с разных листов книги, использовал следующий код

```
Sub аа()
Dim a As String
Dim b, c As Double
a = Worksheets("январь 2023 фактический рк").Range("A3").End(xlDown).Row
b = Worksheets("январь 2023 фактический рк").Range("D3").End(xlDown).Row
c = Worksheets("Анализ РК").Range("B5").End(xlDown).Row
Cells(2, 8) = a
Cells(2, 9) = b
Cells(2, 10) = c
End Sub
```

По факту в каждом столбце 229 значений, а выводит 231, 5 и 7 значений по каждому столбцу

Comment: Ссылку на пример с данными дадите?

Comment: ну к примеру, на обоих листах есть один столбец общий, но на каждом листе есть свои данные, количество строк которых нужно определить

Comment: Ну, к примеру, анализируете код и смотрите данные на листах, находите решение :)

Answer (score 0):

Пройдитесь циклом по файлу.
к примеру:

```
a = 0

Do
    if cells(a, 1) = "" then Exit Do 
a = a + 1
Loop
```

Номер столбца у ячейки указываем тот, в котором будут точно значения, либо добавляем доп. проверки циклом по остальным столбцам. Если есть вероятность наличия пустых строк - также исследуем это условие кодом.
Стандартные функции VBA не дадут вам идеальный результат в 100% случаев.